# free jqGrid : how to assign function return value to edit/addNew form field?

Tags: jqgrid, free-jqgrid

my code is

```
  ......
  ......
  {label: 'Reason'
   ,name: 'reason'                      
   ,width: 60
   ,editable: true
   ,editrules : { required: true}
   ,editoptions: { maxlength: 4 }
   ,formoptions:{rowpos: 5, colpos: 2, label: " <a href='javascript:selectRsnRecord()' " +
                           " title='See the list of all Reason codes' > Reason</a> " } 
                },

  ......
  ......
```

when I click on Reason label on the Edit/Add new form, the function selectRsnRecord() gets the reason value. This new reason value should go into Reason text box on the edit/add new form. I can able to get the reason value but I'm not getting how to show/assign the value on the jqGrid edit /add new form text box. with the following, I can see the new reason value on the grid.

```
myGrid.jqGrid('setCell', selectedRowId, 'reason', newValue);
myGrid.jqGrid('getLocalRow', rowid).reason= newValue;
```

I'm using jqgrid 4.9.0 version and its not possible for me to use any other plugin.

Please let me know how to show/assign the new reason value on the jqGrid edit /add new form text box itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Free jqGrid uses still the same rule for assigning ids to form field as old version of jqGrid do: it's just the name of the column. Thus you can get/set the value in input filed of the editing dilaog using `$("#reason").val`. You can use `$("#reason").val("newValue")` in `selectRsnRecord` to assign `newValue` in the form dialog.

Comment: You are awesome as always!!